# what can i do to print that "password has changed successfully"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Below gives my code for changing the password.please help me to print that 'your password has changed successfully'.

```
public function passwordupdate(Request $request){

    $user=user::find(Auth::user()->id);

    $validator=Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'password' => 'required|min:6|max:14',                        
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|max:14',                        
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){         
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['password'=>'Please check the password you given']);

    }else if (!Hash::check($request->cpassword, Auth::user()->password)) {
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['password'=>'Error!!Please check the current password you given']);
    }

    else{

        $user->password=bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return back with a flash message to the user.

Instead of

```
return redirect()->back();
```

You could do

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'your password has changed successfully');
```

And then in your blade file show the message

```
@if( Session::has('message') )
  <div class="alert">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Laravel's [Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) functionality. The code will be like:

```
$request->session()->flash('message', 'Password Changed Successfully!');
return redirect()->back();
```

You can retrieve the message in the view like this:

```
@if( Session::has('message') )
  <div class="alert">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```

Hope it helps..!!